# Grammar in context Question

Tags: grammar

> I hope you don’t mind me messaging you.

Is ‘me’ the subject of the gerund phrase, or what would we call the phrase ‘me messaging you’? What’s the structure of the phrase ‘me messaging you’? How is it functioning in the sentence?

Comment: I don't think it's a *gerund phrase*.  I think it's some flavor of *subordinate clause*, but I couldn't tell you the exact name.  Either way, yes, "me" should be the subject.

Comment: What kind of subordinate clause it is? A subordinate clause usually begins with a subject and verb, but the clause, ‘me messaging you’ starts with an objective case. What do you think about it?

Comment: I think it's a *participle phrase*. Participles or participle phrases are often used to make a shortened form of a subordinate clause.

Comment: @Sarosh  Tᴚoɯɐuo seems to have given you the answer.  I'm not an expert on how these things are named, as I don't find it very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

**me messaging you** refers to an action but not a finite one, that is, not 
 to an action happening at a particular moment.

Rather it refers to the notion of the action. The clause has a nominal role. It fits in the {something} slot:

> I hope you don't mind {something}.

It could be paraphrased

> I hope you don't mind *that I have messaged you*.
>
> I hope you don't mind *that I will be messaging you*.

We don't know the time of the action and cannot say, without context, whether the reference is to something already done or to something contemplated, because it is not a finite clause.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! So can I say ‘me messaging you’ can be interpreted as the reduced clauses  of any of these clauses, ‘that I have messages you’ or ‘I will be messaging you’ ?

Comment: No, I would not call it a "reduced" version of those clauses.

Comment: Then  what? I guess ‘me messaging you is a non-finite clause then, right? Would you consider ‘me’ as the subject of that non-finite clause?

Comment: The verb in **me messaging you** is non-finite.   The speaker, the referent of "me", is the entity who has been doing or who will be doing the messaging.

Comment: Thank you again! So can we say that ‘me’ is the subject of that nominal non-finite clause?

Comment: That is certainly one way of analyzing it.

Comment: All right, your input is highly appreciated.